# DevOps Xamarin.iOS Build pipeline is also building Droid project

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I created a build pipeline to build a Xamarin Forms app. I added the task:

`Build Xamarin.iOS solution **/*.sln`

The build is working fine for Xamarin.iOS but it also builds the Xamarin.Android project which is not required for me.

As you can see in this log, it tries to build the Android version which causes an error for me:

> 'PushNotification' could not be found (are you missing a using
>   directive or an assembly reference?)
>   [/PATH/NAME_OF_PROJECT/Droid/NAME_OF_PROJECT.Droid.csproj]

Comment: When you build the solution, you build everything including the android version. In your situation you only want to build a specific project.

Comment: @RPelzer, Yes, this is the situation. I want to build only the Xamarin.iOS project which is working fine locally

Comment: try this - https://dailydotnettips.com/exclude-project-from-visual-studio-team-servicesvsts-build-definition/

Comment: Instead of putting the `**/*.sln` specify the the iOS `proj`

Comment: @MohitVerma-MSFT, I will try it now. It looks exactly like what I want to achieve.  Thanks

Comment: Sure @Ali123. Try and let me know how it works  out for you or if you need any help.

Comment: @ShaykiAbramczyk, I didn't know that you could select csproj instead of sln. This is good to know. But, now i am getting an error while restoring nuget package because of the path: Path to solution, packages.config, or project.json

Comment: @Ali123 In the nuget restore step you can put the .sln, only in the build step out the .csproj

Comment: @ShaykiAbramczyk It's disabled for me.i can't change the path

Comment: @Ali123 Can you share yout full build definition?

Answer (score 1):

On the "Build Xamarin.iOS solution" step, click the "link settings" button.  The following dialog will come up.  Select "Solution" from the dropdown and "Unlink":

[image: Unlink dialog box]

This will enable the "Solution" field to be editable.  In there, you can update it to be `**/*iOS*.csproj`.

[image]

Rebuild, and you will notice it no longer builds the Android project, and only builds the iOS project.

Answer (score -1):

It's building all of the projects in your solution. What we have done in the past to get around this is to make a copy of your .sln file, open, remove all projects that aren't related to iOS, and use that as the .sln for building iOS.

Comment: There should be a better way to configure this.
There is a way in Visual Studio for windows to exclude projects and keep them as files only. I don't see this option in Visual Studio for Mac. Thanks for your answer.